# Office add-in name not appearing in user's language

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I've developed an Office add-in for Outlook and I'm trying to get it to display in the user's language in the Applications popup. When I open the add-in, it displays correctly in the users' language, but from the Applications popup, it's still showing in the default language. How can I get it to show up in the user's language?

Here is the section of the manifest file that I thought related to the name of the add-in as it appears in the Applications popup. I can confirm that I changed my user language to "français (Canada)".

```
<DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
<DisplayName DefaultValue="EU Locale (default)" >
    <Override Locale="fr-CA" Value="EU Locale (fr)" />
```

Also, here is a screenshot of what the add-in looks like in the Applications popup: [image]